# Google Developer Console Beta Testing Link does not work

Tags: android, beta-testing

Yesterday I've published my first app in Google Play Store as a beta version.
The status changed already yesterday from `Draft` to `Published`.

Meanwhile, 12 hours later my beta-link still doesn't work:
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/[my_app]

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you created a Google+ community for your beta test?

Comment: Or a Google Group? You need to give your testers the permission to test the app either via Google+ community or Google Group.

Comment: So basically Beta-Test is not possible without Google+ community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dector and MF6265 already mentioned.
You'll need a Google+ Community or a Google Group.
In this case I've used the Google Group, which works as a mail distributor.